# Why does TS give the following error in my case: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following code:

```
<CriterionCheckbox
  key={exp.value}
  checked={expandedFilters.experience.includes(exp.value)}
  title={exp.label}
  width='25%'
  onChange={() =>
  handleExpandedFilter(
  exp.value,
  expandedFilters.experience as number[],
  'experience',
    )
}
  />
```

Also I have this type type which is setted with the 3rd string in the code above.

> ExpandedFiltersState = {   [key: string]: string | Moment[] | number[]
> }

And I get the following error:

> Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'never'

Why? How can I avoid it?

Comment: Error is in the 3rd string of my code above (checked = ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following, simpler example:

```
interface Moment {
  prop1: string;
}

const z:  Moment[] | number[] = [];
z.includes(1)

// TS2345: Argument of type '1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Moment & number'.   
// Type '1' is not assignable to type 'Moment'.

// Signature of includes in this case:
Array<T>.includes(     
  searchElement: Moment & number,     
  fromIndex: number | undefined): boolean
```

Note that if z can be either Moment or number, than, for includes to succeed in either case, searchElement must be an union of Moment & number

Now, let's take a look at your example:

```
expandedFilters.experience 
// type is string | Moment[] | number[]
```

Typescript again tries to make union of element types.
As string is not an array, it is impossible.

Therefore, it infers type of searchElement to never.